# Parsing failing with LXML Xpath using utf-16

Tags: python, parsing, xpath, lxml, utf-16

I am parsing the following page: http://www.amazon.de/product-reviews/B004K1K172
Using lxml based etree for parsing.

Content variable containing the entire page content

Code:

```
myparser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding="utf-16") #As characters are beyond utf-8
tree = etree.HTML(content,parser = myparser)
review = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='productReviews']/tr/td[1]/div[1]/text()")
```

This is returning an empty list.

But when i change the the code to:

```
myparser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding="utf-8") #Neglecting some reviews having ascii character above utf-8
tree = etree.HTML(content,parser = myparser)
review = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='productReviews']/tr/td[1]/div[1]/text()")
```

Now i am getting proper data with the same Xpath. 
But most of the reviews getting rejected.
So is this the problem with lxml based xpath or mine xpath implementation?

How can i parse the above page with utf-16 encoding?

Comment: I think you should use `tree.xpath(".//*[@id='productReviews']/tr/td[1]/div/text()")`. Moreover, http://www.amazon.de/product-reviews/B004K1K172 is encoded in ISO-8859-15, but not in utf-16.

Comment: The xpath was just for picking first review.Code keeps on cycling through reviews by changing last div[n] value.I will check the lxml xpath using ISO-8859-15 encoding.

Comment: @nymk.Thanks for the suggestion.Now i am able to parse the page successfully using ISO-8859-15 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion of nymk
Parsed the page using ISO-8859-15 encoding.Thus the changing the following line in the code.
myparser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding="ISO-8859-15")
But changes has to made in SQL so as to accept encoding other than utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

To get the character encoding from http headers automatically:

```
import cgi
import urllib2

from lxml import html

response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.amazon.de/product-reviews/B004K1K172")

# extract encoding from Content-Type 
_, params = cgi.parse_header(response.headers.get('Content-Type', ''))
html_text = response.read().decode(params['charset'])

root = html.fromstring(html_text)
reviews = root.xpath(".//*[@id='productReviews']/tr/td[1]/div[1]/text()")
```